# Trying to make my css grid system responsive

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my grid system (using css) responsive.

```
#results {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
      
}
```

I've been trying for a while and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What exactly is your error? You are trying to accomplish what exactly? What have you tried?

Comment: show your HTML so we can give you a working example.  Include the children of `#results` element with that ID